# When trying to get data from Procedure : PL/SQL - Numeric or Value Error

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I need to send and get back data via c # with the oracle stored procedure.

So I edited my parameters and code.
But when I try to read the data, I get an error while execute the reader.
There are no problems with oracle connections so I just show where I added the parameters
My c# code is below :

```
 object piece_num_id =gridViewMain.GetFocusedRowCellValue(gridViewMain.FocusedColumn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_piece_num_id", OracleDbType.Int32).Value =Convert.ToInt32(piece_num_id);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_piece_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_material_code", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_steel_grade", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_tickness", OracleDbType.Double).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_width", OracleDbType.Double).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_length", OracleDbType.Double).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_pieces_count", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_coating", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_paint_code", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_surface_type", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_surface_quality", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_quality_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_spec_no", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_inner_diameter", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_trapez_form", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_net_weight", OracleDbType.Double).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_gross_weight", OracleDbType.Double).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_product_name_1", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_product_name_2", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_label_text", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_mother_coil", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_reference", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
```

Defining an oracle procedure is as follows :

```
  PROCEDURE semifinished_lable_data(p_piece_num_id    IN INTEGER,
                                    p_piece_id        OUT STRING,
                                    p_material_code   OUT STRING,
                                    p_steel_grade     OUT STRING,
                                    p_tickness        OUT NUMBER,
                                    p_width           OUT NUMBER,
                                    p_length          OUT NUMBER,
                                    p_pieces_count    OUT NUMBER,
                                    p_coating         OUT STRING,
                                    p_paint_code      OUT STRING,
                                    p_surface_type    OUT STRING,
                                    p_surface_quality OUT STRING,
                                    p_quality_id      OUT STRING,
                                    p_spec_no         OUT STRING,
                                    p_inner_diameter  OUT NUMBER,
                                    p_trapez_form     OUT STRING,
                                    p_net_weight      OUT NUMBER,
                                    p_gross_weight    OUT NUMBER,
                                    p_product_name_1  OUT STRING,
                                    p_product_name_2  OUT STRING,
                                    p_label_text      OUT STRING,
                                    p_mother_coil     OUT STRING,
                                    p_reference       OUT STRING)
```

When I try to get data from this procedure , 
I encountered this error , 
It seems to exist in the error select query in the procedure.

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-06502: PL/SQL:
>   Numeric or Value Error

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a problem with the datatype of one of the tables used by the stored procedure. For example you are sending a width of 123 and the table has the column defined as NUMBER(2). You should check only the 7 NUMBER parameters.

I can't be more accurate without the tables definition and the value you are providing to the SP